# One connection to DB for app, or a connection on every execution?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm using [psycopg2](https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2/) library to connection to my postgresql database.
Every time I want to execute any query, I make a make a new connection like this:

```
import psycopg2

def run_query(query):
    with psycopg2.connect("dbname=test user=postgres") as connection:
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute(query)
        cursor.close()
```

But I think it's faster to make one connection for whole app execution like this:

```
import psycopg2


connection = psycopg2.connect("dbname=test user=postgres")


def run_query(query):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query)
    cursor.close()
```

So which is better way to connect my database during all execution time on my app?

I've tried both ways and both worked, but I want to know which is better and why.

Comment: PostgreSQL connections are _processes_, which are expensive to create.  So keeping a single connection, or a connection pool is more efficient, assuming that the overhead is significant for your app.

Comment: Why don't you measure this yourself? Usually you would use a connection pool between the app and database.

Comment: Note that in the second case(`run_query`) you will need to explicitly handle the transaction e.g. use `connection.commit()` or `connection.rollback` as you are no longer using the `context` manager form(`with`). This can be dealt with using `try/except`.  Or you can use [autocommit](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/connection.html?highlight=autocommit#connection.autocommit).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should strongly consider using a connection pool, as other answers have suggested, this will be less costly than creating a connection every time you query, as well as deal with workloads that one connection alone couldn't deal with.

Create a file called something like mydb.py, and include the following:

```
import psycopg2
import psycopg2.pool
from contextlib import contextmanager

dbpool = psycopg2.pool.ThreadedConnectionPool(host=<<YourHost>>,
                                      port=<<YourPort>>,
                                      dbname=<<YourDB>>,
                                      user=<<YourUser>>,
                                      password=<<YourPassword>>,
                                      )

@contextmanager
def db_cursor():
    conn = dbpool.getconn()
    try:
        with conn.cursor() as cur:
            yield cur
            conn.commit()
    """
    You can have multiple exception types here.
    For example, if you wanted to specifically check for the
    23503 "FOREIGN KEY VIOLATION" error type, you could do:
    except psycopg2.Error as e:
        conn.rollback()
        if e.pgcode = '23503':
            raise KeyError(e.diag.message_primary)
        else
            raise Exception(e.pgcode)
     """
    except:
        conn.rollback()
        raise
    finally:
        dbpool.putconn(conn)
```

This will allow you run queries as so:

```
import mydb

def myfunction():
    with mydb.db_cursor() as cur:
        cur.execute("""Select * from blahblahblah...""")
```

Answer (score 1):

Both ways are bad. The fist one is particularly bad, because opening a database connection is quite expensive. The second is bad, because you will end up with a single connection (which is too few) one connection per process or thread (which is usually too many).

Use a connection pool.